# Why using strcpy the array has to be changed into (*)

Tags: c

I've been wondering why in some codes like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
   char src[40];
   char dest[100];
  
   memset(dest, '\0', sizeof(dest));
   strcpy((char*)src, "This is tutorialspoint.com");
   strcpy((char*)dest, src);

   printf("Final copied string : %s\n", (char*)dest);
   
   return(0);
}
```

Has need this `(char*)`? strcpy requires the address of that array so only src or dest is enough. But in some codes people change into (char*).

Question is why some people do it when normal src and dest also works :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
   char src[40];
   char dest[100];
  
   memset(dest, '\0', sizeof(dest));
   strcpy(src, "This is tutorialspoint.com");
   strcpy(dest, src);

   printf("Final copied string : %s\n", (char*)dest);
   
   return(0);
}
```

And isn't `(char*)` changing the array `char src[40]` itself ? It contains the data and changing it into arrays of pointers doesn't mix this when it has already some data in him ?

What do I mean is src is an address and the address type is changes into a pointer ? I don't understand the syntax and the consequences when the array has some data. Is the character now the address that points to nothing ???

Comment: It's not necessary , and people who do it don't understand the language

Comment: @Mariatto I doubt that you have seen a code like that strcpy((char*)src, "This is tutorialspoint.com"); in a professional project. You could see a code like that memset( (char * )dest, '\0', sizeof(dest)); As for code of beginners then there is nothing to discuss.

Comment: You might want to find a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to take the place of tutorialspoint.com.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I've seen it in some STM32 tutorials about I2C.

Comment: People do this because they use C++ compilers to compile C code. Basically speaking - they do not know what they are doing

Answer (score 1):

> Has need this `(char*)`?

No, there's no need. The `char[40]` (array) *decay* into a pointer to the first element in the array when passed to the function. A pointer to the first element in the array in this array is of type `char*`, which is exactly what the function requires.

> And isn't `(char*)` changing the array char `src[40]` itself ?

No, it's just an unnecessary cast.

Answer (score 1):

With few exceptions, a reference to an array decay into a pointer to its first element.<sup>[1]</sup> That means that

```c
strcpy( src, ... )
```

is equivalent to

```c
strcpy( &(src[0]), ... )
```

Similarly,

```c
strcpy( (char*)src, ... )
```

is equivalent to

```c
strcpy( (char*)&(src[0]), ... )
```

In both cases, you end up with a pointer of type `char *` which points to the first element of `src`. The cast is unnecessary, and it should be avoided.

---

1. Notable exceptions: `sizeof( a )` and `&a`

Answer (score 1):

The cast is unnecessary.

The first argument to `strcpy` is expected to have type `char *`.  The argument `src` has type array of `char`, and arrays when used an expression *decay* to a pointer to its first elements, so such a pointer would have type `char *`.

So what is being passed to the function is a `char[]` which decays to a `char *` which matches what the function expects, so the cast is not needed.